# Функция .load() дублирует блок, вместо обновления после обработки ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

В результате $.ajax выводится сообщение и нужно обновлять div. 
Попробовал `$("#reload").load("#reload")`, но она дублирует код, и получается что внутри блока `#reload` появляется идеентичный блок `#reload`:

```
<div id="reload">
   <div id="reload"></div>
</div>
```

В блоке `#reload` есть php код, который нужно перезагружать.

HTML:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="reload"><?php echo $val; ?></div>
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {
        'xxx' : xxx,
        'yyy':yyy
    },
    success: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
        $("#msg").append(html);
        $("#reload").load("  #reload");
    },
    error:  function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы после успешного ajax запроса, обновлялась и перезагружался блок `#reload` в котором находится php код.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, опишите конкретно что нужно, и что именно не получается

Comment: Вам следует использовать: `$("#reload").html(html);` после того как вставляете код в `#msg` хотя я смысла тоже не особо понял, может вы хотите передать по аяксу и значение в блок #reload и сообщение в блок #msg?

Comment: по аяксу значение передается в #msg, с этим все ок. Нужно еще обновлять\ перезагружать #reload

Comment: @RQEST Мне кажется, если вы в качестве ответа от сервера получите JSON ответ то так будет намного проще работать, и вам не нужно будет обновлять блок целиком, а только контент внутри него..